# Ubuntu/Linux Equivalent of Checking for Warnings in Device Manager in Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, device-manager

Is there an equivalent program available on Linux/Ubuntu systems that does the same functions as checking for device warnings in the Windows' Device Manager?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: I'm trying to verify all the devices (eg various I/O ports...) on my Ubuntu system is working properly (eg no issue with drivers, system resource conflict...)

Comment: "Yellow Bangs" is that a regional way of saying Warnings in Device Manager?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Phoronix Test Suite](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/phoronix-test-suite/):

> The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and benchmarking platform available for the Linux operating system. This software is designed to effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner. The Phoronix Test Suite consists of a lightweight processing core (pts-core) with each benchmark consisting of an XML-based profile with related resource scripts. The process from the benchmark installation, to the actual benchmarking, to the parsing of important hardware and software components is heavily automated and completely repeatable, asking users only for confirmation of actions.

[image: 1]

Another option is [System Testing](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/checkbox-qt/):

> This project provides an extensible interface for system testing. The
>   results can then be sent to Launchpad.
>
> This package provides a QT4 interface for answering tests.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]